# Is there a simple way list, sort, and save directories to a string?

Tags: python

I have simulating directories in current work directory like this:

```
WorkDirectory/500kstp 
WorkDirectory/1mstp 
WorkDirectory/1.5mstp 
.... 
WorkDirectory/20mstp
```

I hope the elements of an array have the values like below:

```
dirs[0]='500kstp'
dirs[1]='1mstp'
dirs[2]='1.5mstp'
dirs[3]='2mstp'
dirs[4]='2.5mstp'
....
dirs[19]='20mstp'
```

I am learning Python. I noticed that the Python scripts are complicated if I want to list, sort, and re-arrange the directories. If I use Perl, four commands shown below can achieve it.

```
my $line=`ls|grep stp|sort -n`;chomp($line);
my @dirs=split(/\r?\n/,$line);
$_=pop(@dirs);
unshift(@dirs,$_);
```

However, in python, it looks very complicated because Python has to call some modules which are complicated to do so. Any simple way to call Bash scripts to save outputs into a string?

Comment: `chomp( my @dirs = \`ls|grep stp|sort -n\` );`

Comment: Re "*`$_=pop(@dirs); unshift(@dirs,$_);`*", huh? Why are you putting the last entry first?

Comment: sort it. I need to analyze data in time series.

Comment: Oh I see, it's an incorrect fix for your incorrect sorting. Your Perl version is oh so wrong. Asking how to run that same bad command in Python is not the way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the contents of a directory and find entries containing a specific string, you can do:

```
dirs = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if 'stp' in f]
```

If you want to sort it by string, you would then do:

```
dirs = sorted(f for f in os.listdir('.') if 'stp' in f)
```

To sort entries as numbers, you could do:

```
def numericKey(s):
    m = re.search('([^\d]*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)', s)
    if m:
        return m.group(1), float(m.group(2)), m.group(3)
    else:
        return (s,)
dirs = sorted((f for f in os.listdir('.') if 'stp' in f), key=numericKey)
```

Edit: 
to scale the numbers by k and m as has been pointed out elsewhere, you can do:

```
import os, re
def numericKey(s):
    m = re.search('([^\d]*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([mk]?)(.*)', s)
    if m:
        scale = dict(m=1e6, k=1e3).get(m.group(3), 1)
        return m.group(1), float(m.group(2))*scale, m.group(4)
    else:
        return (s,)
dirs = sorted((f for f in os.listdir('.') if 'stp' in f), key=numericKey)
```

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your time and answer.